# Date and Timestamp in python gui form

Tags: python, tkinter

i am writing some code that appends to a CSV file. The application will be used in production and only has to be small and not complex, it should print a GUI that allows users to enter the date, time, and serial number

Currently i have a program that allows me to enter data into 3 boxes, two strings for date and time so i am able to put "/" and ":". I want to be able to use a button to get the date and time and insert in the two boxes, e.g. run the software, wants me to enter a date, i press a button and todays date appears (same with the timestamp), or possible to automatically fill the box with the date and time.

As i mentioned before, currently i have the code so i enter a string in "12/12/2022" and similar with timestamp just so i can get the formatting right. But here is the code.

```
from tkinter import *

def save_info():
    date_info = date.get()
    time_info = time.get()
    
    serialNumber_info = serialNumber.get()
    serialNumber_info = str(serialNumber_info)
    
    print(date_info, time_info, serialNumber_info)

    file = open("test.csv", "a")
    file.write(date_info)
    file.write(",")
    file.write(time_info)
    file.write(",")
    file.write(serialNumber_info)
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
    print(" User ", date_info, " Has been registered")

    date_entry.delete(0, END)
    time_entry.delete(0, END)
    serialNumber_entry.delete(0, END)

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("500x500")
screen.title("Python Form")
heading = Label(text = "Python Form", bg = "grey", fg = "black", width = "500", height = "3")
heading.pack()

date_text = Label(text = "Date * ",)
time_text = Label(text = "Time * ",)
serialNumber_text = Label(text = "Serial Number * ",)
date_text.place(x = 15, y = 70)
time_text.place(x = 15, y = 140)
serialNumber_text.place(x = 15, y = 210)

date = StringVar()
time = StringVar()
serialNumber = IntVar()

date_entry = Entry(textvariable = date, width = "30")
time_entry = Entry(textvariable = time, width = "30")
serialNumber_entry = Entry(textvariable = serialNumber, width = "30")

date_entry.place(x = 15, y = 100)
time_entry.place(x = 15, y = 180)
serialNumber_entry.place(x = 15, y = 240)
register = Button(screen,text = "Register", width = "30", height = "2", command = save_info, bg = "grey")
register.place(x = 15, y = 400)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime` module to get the current time to fill the date and time entry boxes:

```py
...
from datetime import datetime
...

def fill_datetime():
    # get current date and time
    now = datetime.now()
    # fill date
    date.set(now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    # fill time
    time.set(now.strftime("%T"))

datetime_button = Button(screen, text="Fill Date and Time", width=30, height=2, command=fill_datetime, bg="grey")
datetime_button.place(x=15, y=300)

...
```